# C Segmentation Fault on for

Tags: c

I don't know why this program is executing well on Ubuntu but not on debian systems. I got segmentation fault when i call the double `for()` in x and y.

If I comment the double for, all is ok. If I don't comment, I got segmentation fault. Also if you comment all the for content, it also goes in segmentation fault. Input data in order: 128, 0.5, 0

**EDIT**
I apologize to everyone who read this incomplete topic. I wrote it too fast. Let's talk about this code. Imagine you have a lattice with LxL dimension. In each point (x, y) we have a call center. A call center is also defined by two variables: the first one, his status. Online or offline. The secondo one, the label. That's why is useful to use a struct which I called *site*. Every site is connected to his neighbor, in particular every site has 4 neighbor: top, right, bottom, left (also on border). Imagine we have a rho density of call center broken, or also a rho density of call center working, it's the same. Now we populate the LxL lattice with working/not working call center. What happen if someone is trying to call from the right top corner to the left bottom corner the left bottom corner is isolated by broken call center? This program is trying to simulate the cluster connection and propagation. It starts which the population of the area and then, with the *update* function, for every point it verify if the neighbor is of the same status and propagate the lower label. When the program end, we can find lots of cluster with the same label, and check how the cluster percolated.

My code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define RED "\x1B[31m"
#define GRN "\x1B[32m"
#define BLD "\x1B[1m"
#define RST "\x1B[0m"

#define ONLINE 1
#define OFFLINE 0

struct site {
    int status;
    int label;
} typedef site;

void createDynamicArray(site ***array, int L, int N);
void updateLabel(site ***node, int x, int y, int nx, int ny);

int main(void) {

    int L, seed;
    double rho;

    fprintf(stderr, "\nRetrieving data from input file...... ");
    fflush(stderr);

    scanf("%d\n%lf\n%d", &L, &rho, &seed);

    fprintf(stderr, "[%s%sDONE%s]\n", BLD, GRN, RST);

    // Eseguo alcuni controlli sui dati iniziali;
    if (rho == 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[%s%sFAILED%s] Can't start simulation with rho = 1;\n", BLD, RED, RST);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // L'utente non ha fornito un seme specifico, verra' preso da /dev/urandom;
    if (seed == 0) {
        FILE *fp = fopen("/dev/urandom", "r");

        fread(&seed, 1, sizeof(unsigned int), fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }

    // Dichiaro l'array di struct;
    site ***node;
    createDynamicArray(node, L, L);

    // Popolo il reticolo;
    int x, y;
    double r;
    srand48(seed);

    for (x=0; x<L; x++) {
        for (y=0; y<L; y++) {
            r = drand48();

            (*node)[x][y].label = x + L*y;

            if (r < rho) {
                (*node)[x][y].status = ONLINE;
            } else {
                (*node)[x][y].status = OFFLINE;
            }

            //fprintf(stderr, "%d\t", (*node)[x][y].label);
        }

        //fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    }

    for (x=0; x<L; x++) {
        for (y=0; y<L; y++) {
            updateLabel(node, x, y, (x+1)%L, y); // Destra;
            updateLabel(node, x, y, (x + L - 1)%L, y); // Sinistra;
            updateLabel(node, x, y, x, (y+1)%L); // Alto;
            updateLabel(node, x, y, x, (y+L-1)%L); // Basso;
        }
    }

    //FILE *fp_out = fopen("output.dat", "w");

    for (x=0; x<L; x++) {
        for (y=0; y<L; y++) {
            fprintf(stdout, "%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", x, y, (*node)[x][y].label, (*node)[x][y].status);
        }
    }

    //fclose(fp_out);

    /*fprintf(stderr, "\n\n");

    for (x=0; x<L; x++) {
        for (y=0; y<L; y++) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%d\t", (*node)[x][y].status);
        }   
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "\n\n");

    for (x=0; x<L; x++) {
        for (y=0; y<L; y++) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%d\t", (*node)[x][y].label);
        }   
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    }*/

    // Libero gli array;

    return 0;
}

void createDynamicArray(site ***array, int L, int N) {
    int i;
    *(array) = (site **)calloc(L, sizeof(site *));

    if (*(array) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[%s%sFAILED%s] Allocazione dinamica di memoria di (array) NON riuscita.\n", BLD, RED, RST);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i=0; i<L; i++) {
        (*array)[i] = (site *)calloc(N, sizeof(site));

        // Verifica della corretta allocazione dinamica di memoria dell'i-esimo elemento di array;
        if ((*array)[i] == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "[%s%sFAILED%s] Allocazione dinamica di memoria di (*array[%d]) NON riuscita.\n", BLD, RED, RST, i);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

void updateLabel(site ***node, int x, int y, int nx, int ny) {

    // Se il vicino ha lo stesso status, posso propagare il label
    if ((*node)[x][y].status == (*node)[nx][ny].status) {
        if ((*node)[x][y].label < (*node)[nx][ny].label) {
            (*node)[nx][ny].label = (*node)[x][y].label;
        } else {
            (*node)[x][y].label = (*node)[nx][ny].label;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Being a three star programmer in C is not a compliment. TL;DR provide a [mcve] and more details. Use a debugger.

Comment: Also, in this particular case there is no reason to use `***`

Comment: Likely to be `createDynamicArray`; otherwise comments as per Olaf and iharob.

Comment: If I copy-paste the contents of createDynamicArray the program works. But why this is happen? Why the function, which is correct, is failing?

Comment: what does `gdb` (or your favorite debugger) tell you?

Comment: this definition: `struct site {
    int status;
    int label;
} typedef site;` has invalid syntax.  it should be:  `typedef struct site {
    int status;
    int label;
} site;`

Comment: regarding these two lines: `site ***node;
    createDynamicArray(node, L, L);`  the compiler will complain about use an un-initialized variable: `node`.   Suggest: `site ***node = NULL;
    createDynamicArray(node, L, L);`

Comment: there are two(2) code sequences of a 'double for()'  which sequence is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line is the start of the problem that results in a seg fault event

```
*(array) = (site **)calloc(L, sizeof(site *));
```

because the passed in parameter `site ***array,` contains some random value

Suggest: change:

```
site ***node;
createDynamicArray(node, L, L);
```

to this:

```
site **node = NULL;
createDynamicArray(&node, L, L);
```

Then an solid value is being passed: the address of the `node` variable

Then correct the new warnings/errors that will be raised by the compiler.

The result is:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define RED "\x1B[31m"
#define GRN "\x1B[32m"
#define BLD "\x1B[1m"
#define RST "\x1B[0m"

#define ONLINE 1
#define OFFLINE 0

typedef struct site
{
    int status;
    int label;
} site;

void createDynamicArray(site ***array, int L, int N);
void updateLabel(site **node, int x, int y, int nx, int ny);

int main(void)
{

    int L, seed;
    double rho;

    fprintf(stderr, "\nRetrieving data from input file...... ");
    fflush(stderr);

    scanf("%d\n%lf\n%d", &L, &rho, &seed);

    fprintf(stderr, "[%s%sDONE%s]\n", BLD, GRN, RST);

    // Eseguo alcuni controlli sui dati iniziali;
    if (rho == 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "[%s%sFAILED%s] Can't start simulation with rho = 1;\n", BLD, RED, RST);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // L'utente non ha fornito un seme specifico, verra' preso da /dev/urandom;
    if (seed == 0)
    {
        FILE *fp = fopen("/dev/urandom", "r");

        fread(&seed, 1, sizeof(unsigned int), fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }

    // Dichiaro l'array di struct;
    site **node = NULL;
    createDynamicArray(&node, L, L);

    // Popolo il reticolo;
    int x, y;
    double r;
    srand48(seed);

    for (x=0; x<L; x++)
    {
        for (y=0; y<L; y++)
        {
            r = drand48();

            (node)[x][y].label = x + L*y;

            if (r < rho)
            {
                (node)[x][y].status = ONLINE;
            }

            else
            {
                (node)[x][y].status = OFFLINE;
            }

            //fprintf(stderr, "%d\t", (*node)[x][y].label);
        }

        //fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    }

    for (x=0; x<L; x++)
    {
        for (y=0; y<L; y++)
        {
            updateLabel(node, x, y, (x+1)%L, y); // Destra;
            updateLabel(node, x, y, (x + L - 1)%L, y); // Sinistra;
            updateLabel(node, x, y, x, (y+1)%L); // Alto;
            updateLabel(node, x, y, x, (y+L-1)%L); // Basso;
        }
    }

    //FILE *fp_out = fopen("output.dat", "w");

    for (x=0; x<L; x++) {
        for (y=0; y<L; y++) {
            fprintf(stdout, "%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", x, y, (node)[x][y].label, (node)[x][y].status);
        }
    }

    //fclose(fp_out);

    /*fprintf(stderr, "\n\n");

    for (x=0; x<L; x++) {
        for (y=0; y<L; y++) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%d\t", (*node)[x][y].status);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "\n\n");

    for (x=0; x<L; x++) {
        for (y=0; y<L; y++) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%d\t", (*node)[x][y].label);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    }*/

    // Libero gli array;

    return 0;
}

void createDynamicArray(site ***array, int L, int N) {
    int i;
    *(array) = calloc(L, sizeof(site *));

    if (*(array) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[%s%sFAILED%s] Allocazione dinamica di memoria di (array) NON riuscita.\n", BLD, RED, RST);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i=0; i<L; i++) {
        (*array)[i] = calloc(N, sizeof(site));

        // Verifica della corretta allocazione dinamica di memoria dell'i-esimo elemento di array;
        if ((*array)[i] == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "[%s%sFAILED%s] Allocazione dinamica di memoria di (*array[%d]) NON riuscita.\n", BLD, RED, RST, i);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

void updateLabel(site **node, int x, int y, int nx, int ny) {

    // Se il vicino ha lo stesso status, posso propagare il label
    if ((node)[x][y].status == (node)[nx][ny].status) {
        if ((node)[x][y].label < (node)[nx][ny].label) {
            (node)[nx][ny].label = (node)[x][y].label;
        } else {
            node[x][y].label = node[nx][ny].label;
        }
    }
}
```

which compiles cleanly and when the user enters `10 10 10` will output;

```
Retrieving data from input file...... 10 10 10
[DONE]
0   0   0   1
0   1   0   1
0   2   0   1
0   3   0   1
0   4   0   1
0   5   0   1
0   6   0   1
0   7   0   1
0   8   0   1
0   9   0   1
1   0   0   1
1   1   0   1
1   2   0   1
1   3   0   1
1   4   0   1
1   5   0   1
1   6   0   1
1   7   0   1
1   8   0   1
1   9   0   1
2   0   0   1
2   1   0   1
2   2   0   1
2   3   0   1
2   4   0   1
2   5   0   1
2   6   0   1
2   7   0   1
2   8   0   1
2   9   0   1
3   0   0   1
3   1   0   1
3   2   0   1
3   3   0   1
3   4   0   1
3   5   0   1
3   6   0   1
3   7   0   1
3   8   0   1
3   9   0   1
4   0   0   1
4   1   0   1
4   2   0   1
4   3   0   1
4   4   0   1
4   5   0   1
4   6   0   1
4   7   0   1
4   8   0   1
4   9   0   1
5   0   0   1
5   1   0   1
5   2   0   1
5   3   0   1
5   4   0   1
5   5   0   1
5   6   0   1
5   7   0   1
5   8   0   1
5   9   0   1
6   0   0   1
6   1   0   1
6   2   0   1
6   3   0   1
6   4   0   1
6   5   0   1
6   6   0   1
6   7   0   1
6   8   0   1
6   9   0   1
7   0   0   1
7   1   0   1
7   2   0   1
7   3   0   1
7   4   0   1
7   5   0   1
7   6   0   1
7   7   0   1
7   8   0   1
7   9   0   1
8   0   0   1
8   1   0   1
8   2   0   1
8   3   0   1
8   4   0   1
8   5   0   1
8   6   0   1
8   7   0   1
8   8   0   1
8   9   0   1
9   0   0   1
9   1   0   1
9   2   0   1
9   3   0   1
9   4   0   1
9   5   0   1
9   6   0   1
9   7   0   1
9   8   0   1
9   9   0   1
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was seeking! Thank you sir. This issue is due to the undefinied behavior of C because the three star pointer wasn't initializated. Again, thank you.